# Are there any fora for conversing in Classical Chinese?

Tags: classical-chinese, resources

This is not to say my Classical Chinese has progressed anywhere near a level such that I could converse. But I have found such fora amazingly useful in Ancient Greek. You start wondering how to express the common things, instead of sticking to a few topics.

Comment: interesting. may i ask, why, & what do you want to write in classical chinese?

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 just improve my knowledge by trying to write. Others will correct mistakes, suggest improvements... Like we do here for Greek and Latin https://www.textkit.com/greek-latin-forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=60687

Comment: @Ludi Ha...few write in 文言文 today. A contradiction is: though most people lost the ability of writing in “proper” 古文（In fact, In the past writing required much knowledge and training, so was only mastered by 文人）, but they keep literature connoisseurship. Since Classical Chinese and Modern Chinese are actually the same language, unlike other ancient language, ordinary people CAN understand or grasp part of meaning of Classical Chinese materials, which results In that your writings can be judged broadly rather than discussed in a small circle.

Comment: @Ludi That intimidates many people. Or the writings of these who are not intimidated are often harshly criticized as 附庸風雅/拿腔作調/空洞無物/堆砌辭藻/濫用典故/壅贅繁冗/…… （Compared with master pieces of ancient people, it seems as it is）

Comment: @TooskyHierot well, as a foreigner I don’t plan to publish in Chinese, be it Classical or modern. I am just trying to open new ways of training and practicing :)

Comment: @Ludi Haha. I am just explaining why such forum is scarce. The environment is not friendly to 文言文. Because it is really really hard to achieve a standard of making people feel comfortable to read.|･ω･｀)

Comment: @Ludi You might blame on ancient scholars who left sooo vast and brilliant literature heritage.

Comment: @ludi, very good reason :) next: in which period of history, you want your writing style to be liked?

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 I am mainly interested in 孔子 and 孟子，but I think at my current level any period would be fine. I am still learning the basics.

Comment: @Ludi If that is what interests you, you might go straight into 先秦散文, similar to which are 魏晉散文 and 唐宋古文運動派之作品 |･ω･｀)

Comment: confucius, or mencius, well, their texts are quite difficult to comprehend. ok, let's try: can you read these text easily? https://mmis.hkpl.gov.hk/coverpage/-/coverpage/view?_coverpage_WAR_mmisportalportlet_hsf=遐邇貫珍&_coverpage_WAR_mmisportalportlet_actual_q=%28%20all_dc.title%3A%28%22遐邇貫珍%22%29%29%20AND+%28%20verbatim_dc.collection%3A%28%22Old%5C%20HK%5C%20Newspapers%22%29%29&_coverpage_WAR_mmisportalportlet_sort_field=dc.publicationdate_bsort&p_r_p_-1078056564_c=QF757YsWv59H%2FuxqfBwEJA2QaHRpq4VF&_coverpage_WAR_mmisportalportlet_o=0&_coverpage_WAR_mmisportalportlet_sort_order=asc

Comment: the articles in the 遐邇貫珍 was written by missionary Walter Henry Medhurst, or others; in mid 19th century. their literary chinese was acceptable, maybe good, compare to modern times.

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 也許我的錯誤在于認為這樣的文章就算現代文了……該當自罰。

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 it seems those texts were deleted

Comment: @Ludi In the middle of the website there are page numbersԅ(¯ㅂ¯ԅ). The main content begins at page 5.

Comment: @TooskyHierot are you talking about the content linked by 水巷? I just get: “the content was removed by another user”

Comment: @ludi, i added a page of 遐邇貫珍 in my answer :)

Comment: Classical Chinese Wikipedia: https://zh-classical.wikipedia.org

Answer (score 1):

[新文言](http://www.newwenyan.com/forum.php?mobile=yes)
[辞赋论坛](http://zgfxw.net.cn/forum.php?forumlist=1&mobile=2)
Hummm, I cannot find a forum where people converse In 文言文, but the two fora above are mainly for writing In 文言文.
I must say, 文言文 doesn't quite fit into modern environment. The main reason is words for modern things and ideas
are formed in such a different way from the morphology of 文言文 that it looks awkward for a pure 文言文 to contain modern words like 電話/牙刷/激光照排打印機.

Whereas it is possible to elaborate your speech or writing with 文言文, including using 文言句式/文言詞彙/典故/文風 and In many cases it reads really like so called 文言文 （of course it isn't）.

——————EDIT——————

I think the essence of good writing and speech is concision and accuracy. The more words at your command, the nearer you are from that goal. In daily life and on the Internet, people are inclined to use basic and simple words. If you are not a beginner, you will feel this a hindrance to your improvement. It is, even for native speakers. It might be the reason why you are looking for fora discussing Classical Chinese. But it is not necessaryԅ(¯ㅂ¯ԅ). My advice is simple but proved by many: read books writing in formal and literary language and （my personal practice） buy a hefty dictionary, often leaf through it, take down notes of good words you meet.
|･ω･｀)

Answer (score 1):

i think it's a no, to your question. well, maybe you could try here; i guess people can help you.

my barbarian's offer up: expose to the sun (野人獻曝)

to master the writing skill of classical chinese, pay attentions to 虛字 (particles), and 句讀 (~chop "characters stream" into verse)

interested to try?

have fun :)

what's about this pic:

[image]

Comment: sigh 我猜想題主其實並非要寫文言，而是希圖藉此增進漢語吧。寫文言最難看就是文白間雜，半文不白的樣子，偏又是大多人試寫即是如此。主要還是得由于現在語文教育不再採用文言書體，也沒有蒙學教育了。我見還有民國那時語文課本教授文言，小學生習作也很不錯。我印象中寫春遊有什麽“柳桃堆錦”之句，當時覺得樸實平易，甚是不錯。然而，現在其實也能達成一樣的效果。我認為古文今文間並無太大差距，措辭考究考究、韻律把握一下、句式略作變換，便文氣十足了。歸根究底其實不光中國，似乎世界的語文教育都有滑坡，蓋略由科學發展，其餘學問知識佔去了時間而結果如是。雖然，這也是時代潮流，沒什麽必要過於嘆惋。╮(￣▽￣)╭

Comment: "我認為古文今文間並無太大差距" very wrong lah :(

Comment: 哈哈哈，一孔之見罷了。若是古人所說的古文，也即先秦文章，確實差別顯著，但後來晚近時，書面語雖然仍然模仿先秦，但是現在人讀起來也覺得輕松了。即便是先秦文章，個人覺得也只是詞有異義罷了。其他語法上的問題，似乎非常容易溝通聯繫。

Comment: The first folio is hard for me. The second is much easier to at least broadly understand without dictionary : I would try like this marking unknown characters with x “...this is to be sighed at. Whilst my English remote ancestors had not yet fashioned x skirts (i.were in primitive state), Chinese already knew to use silk. In the days of yore the people of Yamolijia? Country only knew to cross the sea and catch fish, x using? wood to build boats, china already had the south pointing needle (compass), made huge boats, ventured into the sea to transport. Only today is it not so. Every country

Comment: “Is prospering? but China is sinking into peril? It’s current use of trade ships is not remotely on par with antiquity and sagacious philosophers have not been x born?. In the time of its ancestors, they only sacrificed x? to the emperor, x afterwards many x praise? unwitting/stupid idols. The trade vessels of all countries travel swiftly, there is no harbour under the sky without them; but the Chinese trade vessels (don’t understand this here ????)  reach far but upon arrival rest? Geluoba? and other places? All countries some times encounter years of famine and send vessels everywhere...”

Comment: “swiftly to the four corners of the world vessels transporting rice xx. But China when suffering? famine only relies upon the local x produce? to x feed? the distressed many, many hence (could also mean many places?) x die?. All countries when the big rivers overflow can （variant of 築？） build stone x dykes? to xx reduce? its harm. But in China the yellow river every year xx overflows? leading to a disaster xxx (here are four characters of which I only know 黎， maybe ethnic groups hurt by the river?). Every country (don’t know this usage of 興）？fire ships.

Comment: When wind and water (conditions?) are all treacherous, they can travel more than 80 Li at a  time, but China does not have a single one and nobody who could build it! In the West every country has fire carts transporting men and goods capable of travelling over 360 Li at a time, but China to reach far (or at most?) only summons (only learned 屬其耆老 last week， lucky me :) :)）riders, that can cover over twenty Li at a time, but usually cover no more than 10+“

Comment: @Ludi Here 属here is not zhu3 “summon”, but shu3 “be” “是”|･ω･｀)

Comment: @Ludi My translation, have fun! 这真是令人喟叹呀！我那创立英国的祖先还没有齐备冠帽衣裳之时，中国人已经知道运用丝帛；亚美利加人（美国人；或美洲人）只知道乘船在海上捕鱼，凿空木头制成舟船（的时候），中国人已经拥有指南针，制造大船，出海运载。今天不一样了：各国日月进步强盛（互文翻译），而中国每况愈下，其现在用的那些商船，常常还不及古时的；圣哲之人久未诞生（梃字无关乎此，似讹字），（大概是因为）其祖宗诚心祭祀上天，而乃后纷纷崇拜没有知觉的偶像（比如说泥塑的神、佛等）。各国的商船风驶疾行，天下没有哪个港口见不到它们；而中国的商船笨拙缓慢，最远也只是到了息力葛罗巴（新加坡？未知此地名之音译）等地方。各国偶尔遇上荒年，迅速派船往各个方向去，运粮食回来赈济灾眚；而中国遇到饥荒，只能依靠本国，千万百姓中饥馑困乏的人，齐齐（只能）坐以待毙。各国大江泛滥时，就能筑造石塘，永远杜绝其灾害；而中国黄河每年决堤酿祸，众庶民遭水淹。各国纷纷兴造火船（烧火的船，蒸汽轮船），（即便）遇上风向水流都相悖，每小时（也）可以行驶八十里；而中国一无所有，也没有人懂得制造。泰西各国都有火车，人员货物一并运载，每小时可以走三百六十多里；而中国最快的就是乘车骑马了，每小时可以驰行二十多里，（但如果只是）平常旅行，每小时只不过十多里罢了。

Comment: @ludi, reading without dictionary; i would say, your "chinese-ability" is excellent :) now, forget the meaning, can you find out the "pattern" of the text? maybe, you disclose your email, we could communicate better.

Comment: by the way, "火車" is what hongkonger called "train", although "fire carts" is more interesting :)

Comment: get it, you may delete the post :)